# push to Azure DevOps git repo: GCM: NullReferenceException

Tags: windows, git, azure-devops, git-credential-manager

I installed GCM (Git Credential Manager) on my Windows OS. Using it I can `push` to [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) and [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) repositories, successfully. But about [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/):

```
>git push Azure master
fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Then prompt for username (independent of GCM).

With trace:

```
>SET GIT_TRACE=1

>SET GCM_TRACE=1

>git push Azure master
17:34:02.362309 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
17:34:02.364307 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git push Azure master
17:34:02.370303 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https Azure https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/OpenLib/_git/Android
17:34:02.382598 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:34:02.383601 git.c:671               trace: exec: git-remote-https Azure https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/OpenLib/_git/Android
17:34:02.384601 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-remote-https Azure https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/OpenLib/_git/Android
17:34:02.399961 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:34:03.391539 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
17:34:03.613232 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:34:03.615233 git.c:671               trace: exec: git-credential-manager get
17:34:03.615233 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager get
17:34:03.698676 ...\Common.cs:744       trace: [Main] git-credential-manager (v1.18.0) 'get'
17:34:03.793588 ...\Git\Where.cs:348    trace: [FindGitInstallations] found 1 Git installation(s).
17:34:03.802579 ...Configuration.cs:222 trace: [LoadGitConfiguration] git All config read, 38 entries.
17:34:03.809873 ...\Common.cs:543       trace: [LoadOperationArguments] useHttpPath = ''.
17:34:03.879804 ...\Common.cs:85        trace: [CreateAuthentication] detecting authority type for 'https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/OpenLib/_git/Android'.
17:34:04.749863 ...uthentication.cs:229 trace: [DetectAuthority] detected 'https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/' as Azure DevOps from GET response.
17:34:04.757022 ...\Program.cs:601      trace: [Run] ! error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.
17:34:04.760018 ...\Common.cs:709       trace: [LogEvent] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AzureDevOps.Authentication.Authentication.<DetectAuthority>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AzureDevOps.Authentication.Authentication.<GetAuthentication>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.CommonFunctions.<CreateAuthentication>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.CommonFunctions.<QueryCredentials>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program.<<Get>b__24_0>d.MoveNext()
17:34:04.769048 ...\Program.cs:601      trace: [Run] fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
17:34:04.793392 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: bash -c 'test "a$SHELL" '\!'= "a${SHELL%.exe}" || exit 127; cat >/dev/tty && read -r line </dev/tty && echo "$line"'
```

---

Other useful information:

```
>git remote -v
Azure   https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/OpenLib/_git/Android (fetch)
Azure   https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/OpenLib/_git/Android (push)
BitBucket       https://mirismaili@bitbucket.org/mirismaili/androidopenlib.git (fetch)
BitBucket       https://mirismaili@bitbucket.org/mirismaili/androidopenlib.git (push)
GitLab  https://mirismaili@gitlab.com/OpenLib/android.git (fetch)
GitLab  https://mirismaili@gitlab.com/OpenLib/android.git (push)

>git version
git version 2.19.1.windows.1

>git credential-manager version
Git Credential Manager for Windows version 1.18.0

>git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslbackend=schannel
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
core.editor='C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
user.name=S. Mahdi Mir-Ismaili
user.email=s.m.mirismaili@gmail.com
gui.recentrepo=D:/I/Documents/CryptoCurrenciesSimulator
credential.usehttppath=true
credential.helper=manager
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.Azure.url=https://mirismaili.visualstudio.com/OpenLib/_git/Android
remote.Azure.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Azure/*
branch.master.remote=BitBucket
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
remote.BitBucket.url=https://mirismaili@bitbucket.org/mirismaili/androidopenlib.git
remote.BitBucket.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/BitBucket/*
remote.GitLab.url=https://mirismaili@gitlab.com/OpenLib/android.git
remote.GitLab.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/GitLab/*
```

---

Another note is that I can push to `Azure remote`, with [Visual Studio Team Services plugin for IntelliJ IDEs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated GCM from **v1.18.0** to **v1.18.2** and the problem solved:

[image]

I think it was relevant to [this BugFix on v1.18.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.18.1):

> Fixes Null Reference exceptions when parameters or contentType are not populated

Answer (score 1):

Hy

I had the same problem with all of my Azure-DevOps-Repos since today.
I believe this refers to the change from Visual Studio Team Services to DevOps.

My workaround was following:

1. I reconfigured GIT to save credentials:

`git config --global credential.helper store`

2. I signed in my DevOps-Account and created a new personal access token
3. I opened one of my repos and executed another fetch

After the NullReferenceException prompt, I entered my username and pasted the created access token inside the password prompt.

Now, on each interaction with the remote i get two NullReferenceException-Prompts but it works now for all of my Azure-DevOps-Repos...

I don't know how this will behave with other Repo-Services like GitHub and so on. I do only use Azure...

This is only a quik and dirty workaround. So I would appreciate if someone could share a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: @Mat - Looks like there's an answer here, just one the answerer feels is suboptimal.